# Controller Servlet in Web Application workflow

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web-applications, servlets, controller

I would like to know what is the starting point of any web application deployed on JBoss/Weblogic/Webphere.

For example, If you take a struts based application the starting point is ActionServlets plays the role of controller which manages all incoming requests. I am sure controller is depends on framework.

If so, please help me identifying the popular frameworks other than Struts, Flext etc., where I can presume ActionServlet as my controller.

Still a question on back of my mind, Wondering is there anything specific to Application Server? if so, any insight would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: and what if there's no dispatching servlet but each servlet act as "the controller" ?

Comment: I believe Request dispatcher is a delegate not a controller like Action Servlet

Comment: You haven't seen my point. You can have web applications using MVC pattern without having a Dispatcher or Action servlet. So first decide which Framework you want to use (if you want to use a framework), and then it will be possible to try to answer your question properly

Comment: I agree there can be multiple servlets. That means more than one controller or multiple entry points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your clarification, I'll try to write down how do I structure simple web apps (without frameworks)

1. a startup servlet, only initializing global stuffs and checking for resources (db pools, jms). Only it's init() method implemented and loaded with order 0.
2. a login servlet, with a login jsp as its main view.
3. a set of welcome pages redirecting the user to the login servlet (in web.xml)
4. a dashboard servlet, with a simple jsp as a view intrumenting menus and providing a nice starting point for the app.

After this, every action/menu, will map to one or more servlet doing all the bacground stuffs and redirecting to jsp views.

Usually I manage each request into a single servlet, doGet() or doPost() method, but  it's not mandatory, depends on what I am doing.

For example, if you have to generate a report and this generation takes time, the servlet simply enque a report request somewhere (JMS queue or starts a Quartz task) and gives back control to the browser with a courtesy page stating that the request has been queued.

There are also scenarios in which a single request from the web UI, functionally impacts more of my "servlets", in such scenarios I chain the requests using the RequestDispatcher utility.

Doing this may lead to code duplication, so a good design of a business class tree is a must. Common business code shared among servlets (which act as the glue between user inputs, business logic and data logic - just like controllers ^^)

Comment: Great!!! Next, once the request landed into servlet, entire life cycle of the request will be handled in a single thread. Correct?

Comment: I understood that the dispatched request to another servlet will be executed in another thread.. it will be a different URL again. Correct?

Comment: I went through few documents, it is not clearly told anywhere. Anything you found?